# Calling actions from HTML buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, I have multiple buttons. Each button calls its own action. How can I assign the actions to the specific buttons.

Comment: are these buttons inside a form ? and you want your action to behave differently when form is submitted via one of them ?

Comment: Yes, every button has its own action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking about multiple submit buttons, here is something for you,

Below is a form with two submit buttons. Note that both these submit buttons have the same name i.e “submitButton”

```
@Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"){
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Button1" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Button2" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Button3" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Button4" />
}
```

Now over to the Controller, the Action takes in an input parameter called string stringButton and the rest is pretty self-explanatory.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string submitButton) {
    switch(submitButton) {
        case "Button1":
           // do something here
        case "Button2":
           // do some other thing here
        case "Button3":
           // do some other thing here 33
        case "Button4":
           // do some other thing here 44
        default:
            // add some other behaviour here
    }
...
}
```

Hope this helps you !

[Source](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-handle-two-submit-buttons-in-html-beginform-in-mvc-3-razor/)

Comment: And if I have more than one action. So how am I going to call it?
And how can I pass the textbox value to it?

Comment: if you mean mroe than 2 submit buttons "by one more action" then I have updated the code

Comment: are you using the above code for this?? it should work, you getting any errors/warnings?